# "invalid signature" JWT Token Opentok

Tags: swift, swift3, jwt, opentok

I am trying to use the Opentok REST API with JWT to generate a video session token. I am using the following credentials to create the JWT following the JSONWebToken documentation at https://github.com/kylef/JSONWebToken.swift.

I have used the generated token for authorisation and followed the documentation at https://tokbox.com/developer/rest/#authentication and called the api from postman, but I am getting Invalid Signature error message. Where am i wrong?
[image]

```
    var claims = ClaimSet()
    claims["iss"] = "3*****2"
    claims["ist"] = "account"
    claims["iat"] = (Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 330, to: Date())?.timeIntervalSince1970)!
    claims["exp"] = (Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 334, to: Date())?.timeIntervalSince1970)!
    claims["jti"] = "\(NSUUID.init())"
    claims["aud"] = "www.example.com"

    let jToken = JWT.encode(claims: claims, algorithm: .hs256("334******************************d5af".data(using: .utf8)!))

    print(jToken)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ram you are calling the session/create rest api. This api requires a project level authentication, however from you claims it looks like you are trying to generate a account level token.

The `iss` should be your API Key/ Project Id and the `ist` should be the string `project`.

Let me know if this helps and works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you figured your issue out by now but the archive mode and p2p.preference are not supposed to be header attributes but part of the body as json

Answer (score 0):

At the Value field of  "X-OPENTOK-AUTH" you first have to Write: "Bearer " + token.
If it doesn't work try changing "X-OPENTOK-AUTH" with "Authorization".